# ROS newbie and questions about adding to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS (and Unix environments) and am trying to go through some of the tutorials. I realize this is probably a basic question.

I'm currently reading through [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/ConnectingToDynamixelBus) tutorial and am running in to a snag.

(I have already already added the stack sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-dynamixel-motor)

In the first step, the tutorial states that my current directory is on the ROS path. (I am currently using a turtlebot) I have attempted to add this path to the directory

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/turtlebot/ros/ros-pkg ...

Then, when running this command
roscreate-pkg dynamixel_tutorials dynamixel_controllers

I receive this error:
ERROR: dependency [dynamixel_controllers] cannot be found

Any ideas?
I'm very confused.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46501/ros-newbie-and-questions-about-adding-to-ros_package_path/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2012-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Managing ROS_PACKAGE_PATH manually is not recommended. It just leads to a messed up environment to easily. Instead, you should follow the install page and the tutorials and use `rosws` to set up an overlay. Have a look at [this page](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) and [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:/home/turtlebot/ros/ros-pkg
```

Otherwise it will remove previous paths.

---

Originally posted by [kszonek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2959/kszonek/) with karma: 459 on 2012-10-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4